# Overriding a javascript function definition

Tags: javascript, monkeypatching

I am trying to monkeypatch a 3rd party javascript library but the original function definition I am overloading keeps getting called.

```js
var ns = {};

ns.topFxn = function(){
    var _me = "me";
    function _toOverride(){
        console.log("This is the original: " + _me);
    }
    function pubFxn(){
        _toOverride();
    }
    console.log("Original");
    ns.pubFxn = pubFxn;
};

//attempt to monkey patch
var oldTopFxn = ns.topFxn;
ns.topFxn = function(){
    oldTopFxn();
    function _toOverride(){
        console.log("This is the overriden: " + _me);
    }
    console.log("MonkeyPatch");
};

ns.topFxn();
ns.pubFxn();
```

OUTPUT:

```
scratch.js:15> Original
scratch.js:26> MonkeyPatch
scratch.js:10> This is the original: me
```

I think this is because this function is indirectly called by another function, and that function might hold a closure on the function it is pointing to - so maybe this isn't possible?  Any suggestions on how to override?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robbie54/f6m53q8h/)

Comment: You can't override nested function definitions, only the main function.

Comment: In this case you have to implement all of the functionality of `oldTopFxn`, and cannot call it anymore. And if `oldTopFxn` utilizes some inner functions, you might have to implement their functionality too, since you can't access them directly. Or you call `oldTopFxn` and fix the result, as far as that is possible. Can you name/link the concrete library and problem you want to patch? so that we might give you a better recommendation, what your options are

Comment: Good to know.  But why not?  If you can elaborate a bit more @Barmar in an answer I'll accept.

Comment: @Thomas the library is dc.js.  The issue is documented [here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1085) and has a fix out soon I think but I was trying to see if I could patch it myself.

Comment: There's no good way to patch that from the outside. But there's no need for that, as far as I can tell, it is [already fixed in the lib itself](//github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/js/dc.js#L5121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override a local function in another function, because of variable scope. The name `_toOverride` is local to each function, and assigning it in your function has no effect on the function with the same name in a different function.

You would have to override `ns.pubFxn`.

```
var oldTopFxn = ns.topFxn;
ns.topFxn = function(){
    oldTopFxn();
    var oldPubFxn = ns.pubFxn;
    function _toOverride(){
        console.log("This is the overriden: " + _me);
    }
    ns.pubFxn = function() {
        oldPubFxn();
        _toOverride();
    }
    console.log("MonkeyPatch");
};
```